Serial or identity define with starting value as max(table)
I have a table with id, name columns id is integer with identity or serial, primary constraints
When I insert first record "id" Is auto generate(insert into tab1(name) values('test2'))with value 1 and second record inserting with "id" Column like insert into tab1(id, name) values(2, 'test2') again 3rd record insert with id auto generate and getting primary key violation error.
How to insert 3rd record without primary key violation?
Trying serial or identity constraint start value should check max of table data each insertion
This we can achieve using sequence but need to achieve with identity or serial
Sequence code is:
CREATE SEQUENCE my_sequence MINVALUE 1000000 START
    (SELECT MAX(id_column) FROM my_table) OWNED BY my_table.id_column;


Don't. This is abusing the autoincrement(sequence/identity) process and will only lead to problems. If the id column has meaning outside of being just an autoincremented number then the column should not have a serial/sequence/identity attached to it. Otherwise, if id is just there to be a unique number then use  serial/sequence/identity and leave it alone.

Id is unique number but first time is insertion is using serial/sequence/identity and second time is deliberately inserting id column data and third time again auto increment but for 3rd insertion auto increment value is 2 instead of 2 it should be 3 and how to achieve it

The point is you should not be deliberately inserting values into id column, just let the sequence take care of that.  Otherwise you will be chasing numbers around forever. For why see here Create Sequence: Notes section.
